# How to extract number that has a unit in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If the table data is set up with a value plus a unit,

for example, `1. "Kilos"` or `34300. "GBP"`,

how to get the number using a functional approach or pattern matching?

Comment: Is the table in a text file, with multiple rows like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/gmk8S7Qk) for example?  Or is it already a mathematica list, with strings like those two for elements?  Do you want to retain the units or just the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions here, mapping `First` or `QuantityMagnitude`.

[image]